# Finding the maximum value of a user-inputted set of values without storing the values in a list

Tags: python, max

I need to create a program that uses while loops to find the largest number that a user enters. The values entered must be greater or equal to 0, and the program quits when the user inputs -1. When the user enters -1, the largest value is supposed to be printed. Lists ARE NOT allowed to be a part of the program. Once the max value is found, the user is asked if they want to find another max value, and if so, the program loops again.

I am having a hard time coming up with the proper input function as well as trying to find out how to find the Max value.

```
print()
number = int(input("Input an integer greater than or equal to 0, or -1 to quit: "))
while number != -1:
    print(number)
    number
    <max number function>
    newNumber = input("Would you like to find the largest number again? (y/n): ")
if number == -1:
    print("Goodbye!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a temporary `max_value` with its initial value is smallest possible number, for example -100:

```
max_value = -100
```

and then update it every times you get new `number`. It checks if the new `number` is bigger that `max_value` then replace it:

```
max_value = max(max_value, number)
```

in your code:

```
print()
number = int(input("Input an integer greater than or equal to 0, or -1 to quit: "))
max_value = -100
while number != -1:
    print(number)
    number
    max_value = max(max_value, number)
    newNumber = input("Would you like to find the largest number again? (y/n): ")
if number == -1:
    print("Goodbye!")
```